# Creating Dictionary from table - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a code to create a dictionary from a table that maps fruits to dictionaries of their quantity in different baskets.

```
table = [['Fruit', 'Basket1', 'Basket2', 'Basket3'],
        ['Apples', 4, 5, 6],
        ['Bananas', 7, 8, 10],
        ['Oranges', 8, 9, 2]]

Expected dictionary: {'Apples': {'Basket1':[4],'Basket2':[5],'Basket3':[6]}, 'Bananas':{'Basket1':[7],'Basket2':[8],'Basket3':[10]}, 'Oranges':{'Basket1':[8],'Basket2':[9],'Basket3':[2]}}

Expected Output:  [Apples][Basket1]= 4
```

Below is what I have so far. I know the last 2 lines don't make sense, but I have a hard time figuring out how to close this one out.

```
basket = [y for y in table[0] if y!='Fruit']
Quantity=[y[1:4] for y in table if y[0]!='Fruit']
Fruit = [y[0] for y in table if y[0]!='Fruit']
a = dict(zip(Fruit, Quantity))
b = dict(zip(a,Basket)
b
```

Comment: Your 'expected' dictionary is not a dictionary.  It appears to be a list of dictionaries.  Also, your table is what?  Not valid python for sure.

Comment: Is it so hard to paste with quotes...

Comment: My apologies.  My table is a list of lists, but just want to convert it to a dictionary

Comment: please make sure you want a list as an output or not. `Expected Output:  [Apples][Basket1]= 4`  while dictionary is of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about the table header row, you can use a dictionary comprehension and enumerate the table rows:

```
>>> {row[0]: {'Basket{}'.format(n): [v] for n, v in enumerate(row[1:], start=1)}
     for row in table[1:]}
{'Apples': {'Basket1': [4], 'Basket2': [5], 'Basket3': [6]},
 'Bananas': {'Basket1': [7], 'Basket2': [8], 'Basket3': [10]},
 'Oranges': {'Basket1': [8], 'Basket2': [9], 'Basket3': [2]}}
```

If you must match the headers, then this approach should work:

```
headers = table[0][1:]
{row[0]: {header: [v] for header, v in zip(headers, row[1:])}
          for row in table[1:]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table = [['Fruit', 'Basket1', 'Basket2', 'Basket3'],
        ['Apples', 4, 5, 6],
        ['Bananas', 7, 8, 10],
        ['Oranges', 8, 9, 2]]
m={}                                      
for i in range(1,len(table)):
    if table[i][0] not in m:
        m[table[i][0]]={}
    for j in range(1,len(table[i])):
        #print m[table[i][0]]
        if table[i][j] not in m[table[i][0]]:
            m[table[i][0]][table[0][j]]=table[i][j]
print m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `header` from the `rows` of data and `zip()` the header with each `row`, e.g.:

```
In []:
header, *rows = table
{k: dict(v) for row in rows for (_, k), *v in [list(zip(header, row))]}

Out[]:
{'Apples': {'Basket1': 4, 'Basket2': 5, 'Basket3': 6},
 'Bananas': {'Basket1': 7, 'Basket2': 8, 'Basket3': 10},
 'Oranges': {'Basket1': 8, 'Basket2': 9, 'Basket3': 2}}
```